# How to compress image before saving - for faster loading/display in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, mobile-application

So I am doing an app that lets you take images (inside CameraActivity, using CameraX) and saves them to local storage. The images are later displayed in a RecyclerView, getting them by their URI.

My issue is that as soon as I open the fragment that contains the recyclerview with the images it gets very very slow. The images are small and don't necessarily need to be in good quality, so I thought of maybe compressing them or just saving them in lower quality right when they are taken to make the loading process faster. Is there any way I can do that right here at this point in the code?

This is some relevant code from CameraActivity:

```
imgView_cameraTrigger.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);

            File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), mDateFormat.format(new Date())+ ".jpg");

            ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build(); // saves image file

            imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback () {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "image saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // Toast.makeText(CameraActivity2.this, "PATH: " + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            ImageView preview = TrackFragment.getImageViewInTrackFragment();
                            preview.setImageURI(uri); // display taken image in imageview in track fragment
                            TrackFragment.setImgPreviewUri(uri); // pass uri to TrackFragment to use it there
                            CameraActivity.this.finish(); // exit camera activity
                        }
                    });
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of maybe compressing them or just saving them in lower quality right when they are taken to make the loading process faster

You probably can give resolution suggestions to CameraX to have it take a lower-resolution image, if that is what you mean. That would tie to code outside of your question.

However, a large part of your problem also lies here:

```java
preview.setImageURI(uri); // display taken image in imageview in track fragment
```

The [documentation for `setImageURI()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) states:

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup

In other words, using `setImageURI()` leads to poor performance and is rarely recommended.

Please use [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/), [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/), or another image-loading library. Not only can they do the image loading on a background thread, but they can also automatically down-sample the image to fit your `ImageView`, improving loading speeds. They can also show a placeholder image while the image is being loaded, cache images in memory to reduce redundant image loads, etc.

FWIW, I demonstrate the use of Glide for image loading in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-internet-003.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack), though changes in the US National Weather Service API may mean that the sample code itself does not work correctly now as it did when I published that final edition.